# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: html

I'm using Espresso and I'm getting this error- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). The images are under project files in espresso inside a folder named images. Whenever I link this code into my website the images don't show but in the live preview in espresso they show. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>ListApp</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile- 1.3.2.min.css"           />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <style>
        img.fullscreen {
            max-height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div data-role="page" id="photos">
  <header data-role="header">
        <h1> List App </h1>
  </header>
  <article data-role="content">
        <ul data-role"listview" data-filter="true">
            <li>
                <a href="#dog">
                <h1>American Pitbull</h1>
                <img src="images/IMG_1870.jpg"
                    alt="Pitbull" />
                <p>This is my sweet, loving Pitbull Kalvin. He's 3 years old and 
                a huge baby. He also likes to go out in style!</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#strobe">
                <h1>My Old Apartment's Lighting</h1>
                <img src="images/IMG_1185.jpg"
                    alt="Strobe Light" />
                <p>We wanted to be able to light up the room in with different 
                   colors and I found this on amazon and it's amazing. Friend's love 
                it and definately improves the mood.</p>
                </a>
            </li>
        <ul>
  </article>
  <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <nav data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon"home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon"grid">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon"info">Info</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
  </footer>
  </div><!-- page -->

  <div data-role="page" id="dog">
  <header data-role="header">
        <h1> Dog </h1>
        <a href="#photos" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext">Photos</a>
  </header>
  <img src="images/IMG_1870.jpg" class="fullscreen" alt="Dog Picture" />
  </div><!-- page -->

   <div data-role="page" id="strobe">
  <header data-role="header">
        <h1> Strobe Light </h1>
        <a href="#photos" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext">Photos</a>
  </header>
  <img src="images/IMG_1185.jpg" class="fullscreen" alt="Strobe Lights" />
  </div><!-- page -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
    # BEGIN WPSuperCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#If you serve pages from behind a proxy you may want to change 'RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on' to something more sensible
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html.gz" [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html.gz" [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html" [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>

# END WPSuperCache

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in relative paths to images.

`src="images/IMG_1185.jpg"` <- relative to current directory

For example when address of site you are on is "http://domain.com/contact", it will be searching for images in `/contact/images`

To fix this, you need to change your image paths to absolute, adding `http://domain.com/` to image source, like

`src="http://domain.com/images/IMG_1185.jpg"` <- absolute path

or add `/` at the beginning of image sources, like this:

`src="/images/IMG_1185.jpg"` <- relative to base directory

I suggest using first method as it is safer.

Comment: So what is the real address of image that works in live preview? Maybe rewrite rules are redirecting request to some other place.

Comment: /Users/admin/Pictures   is the real address of the image

Comment: So where are those images located? You said they are in project directory in folder named `images`. And those shown in live preview are not in that directory.

Comment: I'm using transmit and the images our on my site under public_html, apps, lab 9, images.

Comment: So there is something wrong with rewrite rules. Show your `.htaccess` content and apache configuration file for this domain. Rewrite rules probably are not working at all. RewriteEngine may be off, `.htaccess` files is not beaing read or rewrite module is not loaded at all.

Comment: .htaccess file:                                                              my RewriteEngine is on. It's too long to post in a comment so I'll add it to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting the image folder inside assets folder which is created by deafult when you create a new angular app.
`<img class = "img" width="100" height="19.094" src="assets/images/myimage.png" alt="myImage">`

Answer (score 0):

Mine had the same error when i tried to view my site through github pages. I solved the error by removing the / symbol in front of my path. See example below

Previously `<img src="/images/woman.jpg" alt="dancing woman"/>` (Showed error 404)

Previously  `<img src="images/woman.jpg" alt="dancing woman"/>` (worked perfectly)